# Validate pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, validation

I want to validate the child pom.xml.
Every child pom.xml should have dependency version from parent pom.xml property.

How can I validate child pom.xml file?

```
<kbd><project>
  <groupId>demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
 
  <name>Parent</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.version>3.8.1</junit.version>
  </properties>
</project></kbd>
```

child pom.xml :

```
<project>
 <parent>
    <groupId>demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>example<artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <name>Child POM</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
 
  <dependencies>    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

In child pom.xml , dependency version  should not contain 3.8.1 but it should have property mentioned in parent pom.xml like ${junit.version}.
How to validate the child pom?

Answer (score 0):

Use dependencyManagement in the parent POM instead and then leave out the version numbers in the child POMs.

Comment: That wasn't the question. The question is how to *validate* that it's using the version variable.

Comment: If you do as I suggested, there is not need for validation because the version is drawn automtically.

Comment: And if you never write any bugs, there is no need for validating/testing your code either ;-)

Comment: @Jorn What exactly do you want to validate? That the version of the dependencyManagement is not overridden in the child POM?

Comment: That's a fair question, and one only the OP can answer. It might even be that the answer is "Maven doesn't allow you to validate that".

Comment: Out of the box, Maven doesn't. But you can surely write a Maven plugin that does the job.